# Where can I learn optics equations relevant to multifocal and progressive-focus contact lenses?

Tags: optics, resource-recommendations, geometric-optics, education, lenses

I've tried the usual 2-3 search engines, and had no luck. Ideally a text at Feynman Lectures level (undergraduate math\physics major 2nd-year? level) to start or up to the lower graduate level would be good, but quantum chemistry of constituents in the lenses in situ in the aqueous environment of the tear-hydrated eye would also be great. Not looking for nebulosity due to proteins, etc.

Search results are overwhelmed by marketing materials. (Should I be searching for "discontinuous depths of field" hmmm....)

Search terms or anything, really, for a non-physicist who has learned from The Road To Reality (and, since last year, math and overflow Stack Exchange) that almost anything is approachable for the intrepid and notation-friendly amateur.

Help on recrafting the question is welcome, too. An eventual goal would be a matter simulation model that wasn't *exclusively* classical.

Comment: The question you ask is difficult. The simple equations we teach in introductory courses are appropriate to thin lenses with a single index of refraction and approximately parabolic mirrors. With continuously varying indices of refraction things immediately get harder. There are tricks for when the surface is a plane, like the fact that $n\sin\theta$ is a constant, but I don't know how well they generalize. You should be able to do this with some carefully programed ray tracing, but I'm not 100% confident.

Comment: I think looking into the topic of ray tracing might bear fruit. Here's a paper from 1990 that is on exactly this topic (also, this might be why we only got progressive lenses with the advent of powerful computers - the only way to handle them is to simulate them).

https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-4-431-68159-5_18